# Magento 1.9 - modifying layout

Tags: magento, layout, block, magento-1.9

What is the best way of modifying a layout for Magento 1.9?  I've been updating layouts using the admin backend but now need to do this programatically.  Several articles have mentioned using layout.xml but for some reason, my system isn't picking up the layout updates.

Specifically, this is what I'm trying to modify:

**Original layout**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
        <action method="addOptionRenderer">
           <type>text</type>
           <block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block>
           <template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template>
        </action>
        ...
 </block>
```

**Modified layout**

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
        <action method="addOptionRenderer">
           <type>text</type>
           <block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block>
           <template>catalog/product/view/options/type/newfile.phtml</template>
        </action>
        ...
 </block>
```

My modified layout is located in:app/design/frontend/default/(company name)/(module name)/layout/layout.xml

**layout.xml** (just checking to see if it will add the block, "test"):

```
<layout>
   <default>
      <block type="core/text_list" name="test"/>
   </default>   
</layout>
```

**app/code/local/(company name)/(module name)/etc/config.xml**:

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        ...
    </modules>
    <frontend>
         <layout>
            <updates>
                <(module name)>
                    <file>local.xml</file>
                </(module name)>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>        
</config>
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: Where you added Modified layout?

Comment: What about your module config.xml ? Have you specified layout path correctly

Comment: Just added the config file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things I notice which should be changed:

1. Your layout update file should have a unique name that won’t conflict with existing modules. In your `config.xml` you have specified `<file>local.xml</file>`. The problem with this is, `local.xml` will already be [loaded automatically by Magento](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates). So you should not use that filename for your layout update file if you are trying to add a new one specific to your module, however you may add miscellaneous updates to that file and they will get picked up automatically and **applied last** to the final merged layout.

> Behind the scenes there’s an `<updates />` section of the global config that contain nodes with all the file names to load. Once the files listed in the config have been combined, Magento will merge in one last xml file, `local.xml`.

2. Your layout update file `app/design/frontend/default/(company name)/(module name)/layout/layout.xml` does not appear to be in the right location. You should create [your new layout update file](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf) at: `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/(company name)/(module_name).xml`. Then, you need to update your `config.xml` to point to this file: `<file>(company name)/(module name).xml</file>`.

> Because of the ability to use different themes in Magento and its fallback mechanism, all extension related theme files are placed in “base/default” package for frontend...